# How to set previous State as default values in react material-ui select

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, material-ui

I am trying to use Select from Material-ui. I want to set the prevState as default value. I am able to select the value and save it in my table but not able set that state as default.

Please find the code

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState("");

<Dialog
        open={isOpen}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
        fullWidth
      >
        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Edit</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <FormControl fullWidth>
            <InputLabel shrink id="inputLabel">
              Select severity
            </InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="inputLabel"
              id="severity"
              value={value ? value : ""}
              defaultValue={value} //how to set the prevState in here
              onChange={handleChange}
              displayEmpty
              fullWidth
              MenuProps={{
                anchorOrigin: {
                  vertical: "bottom",
                  horizontal: "left",
                },
                transformOrigin: {
                  vertical: "top",
                  horizontal: "left",
                },
                getContentAnchorEl: null,
              }}
            >
              <MenuItem value={"1"}>High</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={"2"}>Medium</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={"3"}>Low</MenuItem>
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} variant="contained">
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button
            onClick={handleChangeSeverity}
            variant="contained"
            color="secondary"
          >
            OK
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
        Current Value: {value}
      </Dialog>
```

Please find the picture below. I have already selected Low and saved it. When I open the select again it is showing me the empty field. I want to show my existing menuItems (Low/Medium/High) in the highlighted area!

[image]

Thank you!!

Comment: Have you defined the `handleChange` method?

Answer (score 0):

On the `handleChange` event handler, call the `setValue` setter to set the `value` state

```js
const handleChange = (event) => {
  setValue(event.target.value)
}
```

Comment: I have already created and using handleChange function but no luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use "value" and "defaultValue" on the same form element. See this https://deepscan.io/docs/rules/react-misused-controlled-component. If you want one of the value to be pre-selected initiate your state object with that value

And to maintain 2 different values this code might help. I am not using Material components but this should help. Thank you.

```
const selectPriority = () => {
    // you might want to condier using a separate property for previous and new value
    // here i am using an object you can use 2 separate states as well
    const [userValue, setUserValue] = useState({previousValue: "", newValue: "1"});
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const oldValue = userValue.newValue;
        // here I update both the previousValue (to old value) and newValue (to new selection)
        setUserValue({
            ...userValue, previousValue: oldValue, newValue: event.target.value
        });
    }
    return (<div>
                <select
                  id="severity"
                  value={userValue.newValue}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                >
                  <option value={"1"}>High</option>
                  <option value={"2"}>Medium</option>
                  <option value={"3"}>Low</option>
                </select>
                {userValue.previousValue} - {userValue.newValue}
              </div>
    );
}
```